# Using Google Service Account to Resumable Upload Videos

Tags: python, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm using a Google Service Account to upload videos using Resumable Method to Google Drive. The python code works well but I'm running into Google Service Account storage issue.

It seems like Google Service Account can only have 15 GB of storage. Even though I upload the video to a regular Google Drive folder, the video is still owned by the Service Account. Therefore, I tried to transfer the owner of the videos to a different account but it didn't work, the error is `bad request. User message: \"You can't yet change the owner of this item. (We're working on it.)`

Below is my python code that generate an access token from the service account and perform the Resumable Upload

```py
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'creds.json',
        scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    )

    delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('service_account_email')

    access_token = delegated_credentials.get_access_token().access_token
    
    filesize = os.path.getsize(file_location)

    # Retrieve session for resumable upload.

    headers1 = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
    params = {
        "name": file_name,
        "mimeType": "video/mp4",
        "parents": [folder_id]
    }
    r = requests.post(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
        headers=headers1,
        data=json.dumps(params)
    )

    location = r.headers['Location']

    # Upload the file.

    headers2 = {"Content-Range": "bytes 0-" + str(filesize - 1) + "/" + str(filesize)}
    r = requests.put(
        location,
        headers=headers2,
        data=open(file_location, 'rb')
    )
```

Is there a workaround or increase the storage limit of the Google Service Accounts?

Any advice would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this can be increased. Why are you using a Service Account, though? Maybe you would want to use domain-wide delegation and impersonate a regular account?

Comment: hi @lamblichus, I'm not sure if there is any other way to generate the access token for the Resumable Upload Method. That's why I generate the access token from a Service Account and use it to upload video to Google Drive.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `I'm not sure if there is any other way to generate the access token for the Resumable Upload Method`, but if you're just using the Service Account to follow the [2-legged OAuth workflow](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/admin/en/cpanel/2-legged-oauth-diagram.png), you could just use the SA to impersonate a user with enough Drive storage. This way, the SA storage would not be a limitation, since the file would be directly uploaded to the user's Drive. I'll post an answer if you think this workaround could be appropriate for you.

Comment: Thank you, if you can post the a solution, that would be very helpful. I will post my code, so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: Could you please give more details on `I'm not sure if there is any other way to generate the access token for the Resumable Upload Method`? Did you try uploading the file using a regular account? What issue did you face? Also, have you already used domain-wide delegation? (you use `create_delegated` in your code, which is used to act on behalf of other accounts). Also, I think you're using a [deprecated library](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client), better use [this one](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: In order to use the Resumable Upload, I would need an access token. Currently, I generate an access token from the Service Account. With that access token, I'm able to use Resumable Upload. The issue I'm facing is that the Service Account only can upload videos up to 15GB, then it will stop uploading. Therefore, I'm not sure if there is any other way that I can get the access token to use for the Resumable Upload

Answer (score 0):

- You want to use the Service Account to make a Resumable Upload to Drive.
- You want the owner of the video not to be the Service Account, but a regular account which has enough Drive storage capacity.

If that's correct, then you can just have to delegate domain-wide authority to the Service Account, so that it can act on behalf of any user in the domain and, when uploading the file, impersonate the account you want to be the owner of the file.

#### Delegating domain-wide authority:

The process of granting domain-wide authority is explained [here](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts):

- On the [Service accounts page](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), select your Service Account, and while editing the SA, click `SHOW DOMAIN-WIDE DELEGATION` and, on the content that was just displayed, check the option **Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation**.
- Once you've done this, go to the [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) and then go to **Main menu > Security > API Controls**.
- Select **Manage Domain Wide Delegation** in the **Domain wide delegation** pane, and click **Add new**.
- Fill up the corresponding fields: (1) in **Client ID**, enter the SA's **Client ID**, which you can find both in the credentials JSON file and on the Service Account page, and (2) in **OAuth scopes**, add the scopes corresponding to the resources you want the SA to access on behalf of users in the domain. In this case, I guess that's just `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.
- After clicking **Authorize**, you have conferred the Service Account the ability to access resources on behalf of any user in the domain.

#### Impersonating another user:

Now the Service Account impersonate any user in the domain, but you have to specify which user you want it to impersonate. In order to do that, you just have to do a small change in your code. Right now, you're setting the `service_account_email` when delegating credentials via `create_delegated`:

```py
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('service_account_email')
```

That is, the Service Account is acting on behalf of the Service Account. If you didn't want to impersonate another account, there would be no real need for this line of code (it doesn't have any effect, since `credentials` and `delegated_credentials` both refer to the same account (the Service Account).

But since you want to use the Service Account to act on behalf of another account, you have to specify this other account's email address on this line:

```py
delegated_credentials = credentials.create_delegated('user_account_email')
```

That's the only change you need to do in your code. If you have granted domain-wide delegation, the Service Account will act as if it was this other user. It will be like it was this other user who uploaded the file, so this user will be the owner of the file.

#### Note:

- You are using a [deprecated library](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client) (`oauth2client`). Since this is still working, there is no real need to do it now, but please consider changing your code to [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/).

#### Reference:

- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)